# Region as button sencha

Tags: sencha-touch

I've an image as my background and I want to use different regions of the image as buttons which will do different things.![enter image description here][1]

Suppose a image contains four boxes in it. Since they are not separate from images I cannot specifically define there properties but I want to use them as buttons each one doing a different job, is it possible doing this may be using co-ordinates etc... Please help......

Answer (score 0):

You could create four invisible buttons and stretch them out according to the area you want them to take up. In my example below there are four invisible buttons, you can comment out ui:'plain' to see them.

```
           {
            xtype: 'container',
            layout: 'hbox',
            items:[{
                xtype:'button',
                ui: 'plain',
                flex: 1,
                handler:function(){
                    alert('top left')
                }
            },{
                xtype:'button',
               ui: 'plain',
                flex: 1,
                handler:function(){
                    alert('top right')
                }
            }]
        },{

            xtype: 'container',
            layout: 'hbox',
            items:[{
                xtype:'button',
                ui: 'plain',
                flex: 1,
                handler:function(){
                    alert('bottom left')
                }
            },{
                xtype:'button',
                ui: 'plain',
                flex: 1,
                handler:function(){
                    alert('bottom right')
                }
            }]
        }
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I got 4 buttons at the top of the screen.  How can I make them resize so they fill the screen?

Comment: You can give each button a height:'50%', that should fill the screen.

Comment: Couldn't get it to work so I created another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10112124/how-to-make-button-grid-resize-to-fit-screen

Comment: I changed the scss file and added images as iconCls in the code but could not resize the buttons as the screen size change

Comment: One of the answers here  might help you [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10112124/how-to-make-button-grid-resize-to-fit-screen)