# How to make button grid resize to fit screen?

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I took this code from another question and now I'm trying to get the four buttons to fill the entire window.

Nothing that I do seems to have an affect.  The `fullscreen: true` option seems to always be ignored.  What's the trick to know you need to adjust the layout so that it takes all the vertical space?

Ideally, I'd like this solution to work for a `3x3` button layout too.

[image]

---

> app.js

```
Ext.application({

    launch: function() {
        var view = Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
            // fullscreen: true,
            layout: {
                type: 'vbox',
                flex: 1
            },
            items: [{
                xtype: 'container',
                layout: 'hbox',

                items: [{
                    xtype: 'button',
                    height: '50%',
                    text: 'flat button',
                    ui: 'plain',
                    flex: 1,
                    handler: function() {
                        alert('top left')
                    }
                }, {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    height: '50%',
                    //ui: 'plain',
                    flex: 1,
                    handler: function() {
                        alert('top right')
                    }
                }]
            }, {
                xtype: 'container',
                layout: 'hbox',
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'button',
                    height: '50%',
                    //ui: 'plain',
                    flex: 1,
                    handler: function() {
                        alert('bottom left')
                    }
                }, {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    //ui: 'plain',
                    height: '50%',
                    flex: 1,
                    handler: function() {
                        alert('bottom right')
                    }
                }]
            }]
        });
        Ext.Viewport.add(view);
    }
});
```

---

> Standard index.html that uses Sencha Touch CDN.

```
<!doctype html>
<html manifest="" lang="en-US">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sencha</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://extjs.cachefly.net/touch/sencha-touch-2.0.0/resources/css/sencha-touch.css" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://extjs.cachefly.net/touch/sencha-touch-2.0.0/sencha-touch-all-debug.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>

    <body>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified something to meet exactly what you need (3x3 buttons layout). Good luck! :)

P/S: I've removed handler functions to make the source code easier to catch.

```
Ext.application({

    launch: function() {
        var view = Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
            layout: {
                type: 'vbox',
            },
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'container',
                    layout: 'hbox',
                    flex: 1,
                    items:[
                        {
                            xtype:'button',
                            ui: 'action',
                            flex: 1,
                        },
                        {
                            xtype:'button',
                            ui: 'action',
                            flex: 1,
                        },
                        {
                            xtype:'button',
                            ui: 'action',
                            flex: 1,
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'container',

                    layout: 'hbox',
                    flex: 1,

                    items:[
                        {
                            xtype:'button',
                            ui: 'action',
                            flex: 1,
                        },
                        {
                            xtype:'button',
                            ui: 'action',
                            flex: 1,
                        },
                        {
                            xtype:'button',
                            ui: 'action',
                            flex: 1,
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'container',

                    layout: 'hbox',
                    flex: 1,

                    items:[
                        {
                            xtype:'button',
                            ui: 'action',
                            flex: 1,
                        },
                        {
                            xtype:'button',
                            ui: 'action',
                            flex: 1,
                        },
                        {
                            xtype:'button',
                            ui: 'action',
                            flex: 1,
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        });
        Ext.Viewport.add(view);
    }
});
```

Comment: It looks like the 'height:' caused a problem and the 'flex: 1' was removed from the vbox and placed on the two hbox's.  Was there some general rule that I missed?

Comment: yep. `flex` is just to scale relative widths / heights of children components inside a hbox or vbox, so don't use it in **outermost** container

Answer (score 0):

Thiem Nguyen's answer might work for what you need but this will work for stretching the buttons across the screen.

```
view = Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
        layout:'hbox',
        items:[ {
            xtype: 'container',
            width:'50%',
            layout: 'vbox',
            items:[{
                xtype:'button',
               // ui: 'plain',
                flex: 1,
                handler:function(){
                    alert('top left')
                }
            },{
                xtype:'button',
              // ui: 'plain',
                flex: 1,
                handler:function(){
                    alert('top right')
                }
            }]
        },{

            xtype: 'container',
            width:'50%',
            layout: 'vbox',
            items:[{
                xtype:'button',
               // ui: 'plain',
                flex: 1,
                handler:function(){
                    alert('bottom left')
                }
            },{
                xtype:'button',
              //  ui: 'plain',
                flex: 1,
                handler:function(){
                    alert('bottom right')
                }
            }]
        }]
});
```

Comment: I think saying 'flex: 1' on each box is the same as using that 'width: 50%' or 'height: 50%'.  Voted you both up but since Thiem was first, I'm going to accept his answer.  I read through both your solutions in other Sencha questions to learn and I'll be sure to upvote other good answers.  Thanks guys.

Comment: Yes, using flex and width/height is a little redundant. No hard feelings ha.